# Remove timestamp from Java XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, json, date, xmlgregoriancalendar

How do we remove timestamp from XMLGregorianCalendar. I need just the date to be displayed in my JSON. I used  `mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)` but I still see the timestamp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS not turning off timestamps in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978762/jackson-serializationfeature-write-dates-as-timestamps-not-turning-off-timestamp)

Comment: Good to read that you have resolved your issue. You may want to post your solution as an answer. Your question has got an upvote, so others could be interested.

Comment: You probably should not use `XMLGregorianCalendar` with JSON. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Its `LocalDate` class is a date without time of day and thus seems appropriate for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
    public XMLGregorianCalendar removeTime(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        if (value != null) {
            value.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
            value.setHour(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
            value.setMinute(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
            value.setSecond(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
            value.setMillisecond(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
            value.setFractionalSecond(null);
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: If you can use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, instead of `XMLGregorianCalendar`, do. If you can’t, I am pretty convinced that you don’t need both `setMillisecond()` and `setFractionalSecond()`. Either of them should suffice.

Answer (score -1):

```
public String getCurrentDateWithoutTime(){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String dateWithoutTime = sdf.format(new Date());
    return dateWithoutTime;
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend against `SimpleDateFormat`. It was a notoriously troublesome class, and fortunately it is long outdated. Much better to use `LocalDate.now((ZoneId.systemDefault()).toString()`.