# Use springdoc in Spring MVC project with custom message converters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

Adding springdoc to an existing Spring MVC REST API project causes problems with custom message converters. The project configures custom message converters to set the date output to a specific format and to remove fields that contain `null`. This is done using a `@Configuration` annotated class that extends `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` which overrides the `configureMessageConverters` and adds a custom converter as well as the default converters (`addDefaultHttpMessageConverters`).

To add springdoc (version 1.5.1) to the project I've followed the instructions [here](https://springdoc.org/#how-to-integrate-open-api-3-with-spring-project-not-spring-boot), with the minor change of registering `org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerConfig.class` instead of the listed `org.springdoc.ui.SwaggerConfig.class` because the latter doesn't exist.
This requires adding the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation, which in turn requires implementing `WebMvcConfigurer` instead of extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`. By using `WebMvcConfigurer` I can't add the default converters, by using only the custom converter the springdoc JSON is escaped and therefor not valid. If the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation isn't added the swagger-ui.html page is not available.

I want to either use `@EnableWebMvc`, implementing `WebMvcConfigurer` and using the custom converter but prevent escaping of the springdoc JSON by adding the default converters somehow or through some other way. Or I want to use the 'old' configuration, so extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and not add the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation but somehow make the swagger-ui.html page reachable.

How can I achieve either of these options?

**Edit 1**

The configuration class has been annotated using `@EnableWebMvc` and implements `WebMvcConfigurer`, this way the swagger-ui.html page can be reached. The converters are customized using the following method:

```
@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
  List<MediaType> supportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();
  supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

  for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
    if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
      MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter;
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = jsonMessageConverter.getObjectMapper();
      objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
      objectMapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
      jsonMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedMediaTypes);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

This solution is based on [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28016511/14823855).

This way all JSON responses from the endpoints are configured not omit `null` fields and use the configured time zone, the springdoc JSON also isn't escaped.

I've tried configuring a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` bean and adding it to the list of converters however, the springdoc JSON gets escaped making it invalid.

```
@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
  converters.add(customJsonConverter());
  // It's possible to add a converter at a specific index, that to doesn't
  // prevent the springdoc JSON from being escaped.
  // converters.add(1, customJsonConverter());
}
```

**Edit 2**

With the changes mentioned in the first edit everything seems to work fine. Using Tomcat 7. However, the application will be deployed using Tomcat 9 and that results in a (somewhat nondescript) error.

```
[2020-12-15 04:41:42,964] Artifact <artifact-name>:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
15-Dec-2020 16:41:51.791 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
15-Dec-2020 16:41:52.187 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method [manageApp]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1727)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/<application-context>]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 43 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystemFactory.lambda$fromSpringFactories$0(LoggingSystemFactory.java:44)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.DelegatingLoggingSystemFactory.getLoggingSystem(DelegatingLoggingSystemFactory.java:41)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem.get(LoggingSystem.java:159)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.SpringBootConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(SpringBootConfigurationFactory.java:60)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:453)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:385)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:238)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:158)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.initializeNonJndi(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:174)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.start(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:112)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(Log4jServletContainerInitializer.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5128)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 44 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadSpringFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:126)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:122)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:98)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystemFactory.lambda$fromSpringFactories$0(LoggingSystemFactory.java:44)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.DelegatingLoggingSystemFactory.getLoggingSystem(DelegatingLoggingSystemFactory.java:41)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem.get(LoggingSystem.java:159)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.SpringBootConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(SpringBootConfigurationFactory.java:60)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:453)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:385)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:260)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:615)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:636)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:231)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:121)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogAdapter.getContext(LogAdapter.java:39)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:40)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.<clinit>(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:71)
        ... 57 more
15-Dec-2020 16:41:52.189 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method [createStandardContext]
    javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method [manageApp]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1727)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        ... 35 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/<application-context>]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 43 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystemFactory.lambda$fromSpringFactories$0(LoggingSystemFactory.java:44)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.DelegatingLoggingSystemFactory.getLoggingSystem(DelegatingLoggingSystemFactory.java:41)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem.get(LoggingSystem.java:159)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.SpringBootConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(SpringBootConfigurationFactory.java:60)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:453)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:385)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:238)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:158)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.initializeNonJndi(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:174)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.start(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:112)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(Log4jServletContainerInitializer.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5128)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 44 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadSpringFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:126)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:122)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:98)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystemFactory.lambda$fromSpringFactories$0(LoggingSystemFactory.java:44)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.DelegatingLoggingSystemFactory.getLoggingSystem(DelegatingLoggingSystemFactory.java:41)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem.get(LoggingSystem.java:159)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.SpringBootConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(SpringBootConfigurationFactory.java:60)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:453)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:385)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:260)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:615)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:636)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:231)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:121)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogAdapter.getContext(LogAdapter.java:39)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:40)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.<clinit>(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:71)
        ... 57 more
[2020-12-15 04:41:52,197] Artifact <artifact-name>:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
15-Dec-2020 16:41:52.702 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/Users/dopheidp/Programs/apache-tomcat-9.0.37/webapps/manager]
15-Dec-2020 16:41:52.775 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
15-Dec-2020 16:41:52.794 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/Users/dopheidp/Programs/apache-tomcat-9.0.37/webapps/manager] has finished in [92] ms
```

> The artifact name and application context have been replaced with  and  respectively to be on the safe side.

The exception under Tomcat 9 seems to be caused by the springdoc and/or Spring Boot dependency that has been added to the project. By downgrading springdoc from version `1.5.1` to `1.4.8` and Spring Boot from `2.4.0` to `2.3.5.RELEASE` everything works fine under Tomcat 9 (and Tomcat 7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Springdoc has been added to the Spring MVC project using the instructions from [the sprindoc website](https://springdoc.org/#how-to-integrate-open-api-3-with-spring-project-not-spring-boot). This meant adding the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation and changing the configuration class that **extended** `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` to **implement** `WebMvcConfigurer`. So

```
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport { ... }
```

becomes

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurationSupport { ... }
```

These changes cause the message converters that are used to globally configure the JSON responses to break. To resolve this the previous methods used to configure the message converters is removed.

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
  converters.add(jsonConverter());
  addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters);
}

@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter() {
  List<MediaType> supportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();
  supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

  Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
  builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
  builder.timeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));

  MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build());
  jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedMediaTypes);
  return jsonConverter;
}
```

And replaced with the following method. Other ways of configuring the message converters doesn't seem to work, see the question for configuration variants that have been tried.

```
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
  for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
    if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
      MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter;
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = jsonMessageConverter.getObjectMapper();
      objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
      objectMapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
      jsonMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedMediaTypes);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The project currently uses springdoc version `1.4.8` and Spring Boot version `2.3.5.RELEASE` as dependencies, using the latest available versions, springdoc `1.5.1` and Spring Boot `2.4.0` as of this writing, results in an exception under Tomcat 9 preventing the project from starting up.